# password minimum and maximum character

Tags: android, if-statement, passwords

I'm trying to have the maximum character of password that i want to set in my android apps. What would be the best way to code it ? I only have the minimum of 6 character and i want to have maximum of 10 character set password. Here is my attempt:

```
 public void UserSignUp() {
    if(ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().length() >0 && ET_CONFIRM_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().length() >0 &&
            ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().length() >5 && ET_CONFIRM_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().length() >5)
    {
        if(ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().toString().equals(ET_CONFIRM_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().toString())) {
        String SignUpResult = "";
        db = DBMANAGER.getWritableDatabase();
        SignUpResult = CONTENTMANAGER.saveUserPassword(ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().toString(),this);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), SignUpResult, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
         ActivityLogIn();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Confirm Password and Password did not match!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Invalid Input", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer as such but another solution,

Have a look at https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar, nice annotation library.

You can annotate your password fields and it will handle the logic for you...

```
@Password(order = 1, minLength = 4, maxLength = 10)
private EditText passwordEditText;

@ConfirmPassword(order = 2)
private EditText confirmPasswordEditText;
```

Comment: This library is not even maintained now. I like the concept though. You just need to write annotations for validation and pass parameters to it based on your requirement or just skip it.

Answer (score 0):

```
private boolean checkPW(String pw, String pw2) {
        if(!pw.equals(pw2)){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_pws_do_not_match), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        if (pw.length() < 4) {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_pw_too_short), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        if(pw.length() > 10){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.error_pw_too_long), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return false;
        }

        //continue here
            return true;
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this code..

```
if (ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().toString().length() < 6
            || ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.getText().toString().length() > 10) {

        ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.requestFocus();
        ET_PASSWORD_SIGNUP.setError("Password should be between 6 to 10 characters long");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can write this code:

```
// check password
public boolean checkPassword(String password, String confirmPassword) {
    boolean state = false;

    int passLength = password.length();
    if (passLength >= 6) {
        if (confirmPassword.length() != 0) {
            if (password.equals(confirmPassword)) {
                state = true;
            } else {
                makeToast("Password does't match!");
                inputConfirmPassword.setText("");
                inputPassword.setText("");
                inputPassword.requestFocus();
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter confirm password",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            inputConfirmPassword.setText("");
            inputConfirmPassword.requestFocus();
            state = false;
        }
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter 6 digit password",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        inputPassword.setText("");
        inputPassword.requestFocus();
        state = false;
    }
    return state;
}
```